# What will the next Windows Phone Version be called officially?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

So Windows 10 was announced yesterday, with a lot of new features also comming to our beloved Phones running WP. But what will *"Windows Phones"* be called after the Update arrives? I haven't heard or seen *"Windows Phone 10"*, so I think this won't be it. Is it *"Windows 10 Phone"* or even *"Windows 10 for Windows Phone"*? Is there an official statement by Microsoft?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [this article at Windows Central](http://www.windowscentral.com/windows-10-smartphones-called-windows-10), Windows 10 on phones will be called just that, **Windows 10**. No "phone" in there anywhere. This was confirmed by a Microsoft VP at a Q&A session. Paul Thurrott has [a more in-depth write-up](https://www.thurrott.com/mobile/windows-phone/586/goodbye-windows-phone-hello-windows-10).

Update: Microsoft have announced the different editions of Windows 10. The one designed for phones will be called **Windows 10 Mobile**. There will also be an edition for volume licence customers called **Windows 10 Mobile Enterprise**. For more information, see [this article from The Verge](http://www.theverge.com/2015/5/13/8600053/windows-phone-is-now-windows-mobile). Paul Thurrott has a [complete list of Windows 10 editions](https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/3422/microsoft-announces-the-windows-10-product-editions).

Comment: I thought so. Still, usually when talking about Windows you do need to distinguish between regular PC Windows and Phone. Also - what is this site going to be called?

Comment: @Thomas With the united operating systems, there should not be as great of a need to differentiate between the two, since they share the same core features. Granted, there will be differences, but not like there are now.

Comment: @Thomas Damn it. Didn't think about that. But will be clear focused in the Windows running in phone.

Comment: I think Microsoft is making it a bit too easy saying there's just one Windows 10 considering there are in fact a lot of differences between those OS versions (legacy WP7/8 apps vs x86 programs for instance). They might share the same core, but the do not share a lot of core features... But I guess we'll see how it goes, Windows Phone did confuse people as well.

Comment: Yeah I think we'll only be able to tell just how similar they are once we can actually use both final products.

Comment: Seems like the Windows Mobile brading might be back to take the place of Windows Phone https://www.thurrott.com/windows/windows-10/2098/microsofts-plan-to-upgrade-and-update-windows-10-for-desktop-and-mobile